# How to get via Organisation service for Microsoft Dynamics the OptionSet value and Formatted value in different languages?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dynamics-crm

I have a custom .NET application to query and managing data on a Microsoft Dynamics CRM instance.
This application is multilingual and  the user can change via a language switch the language of the application.

For the connection and actions I'm using the OrganizationService and CRMServiceClient from Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.  This is combined with dependency injection to pass the connection to our different classes.

With Ninject this bindings look like
Bind().To().WithConstructArgument("crmConnectionString","the connection string");

Querying and updating the data in Dynamics is working but we are not able to retrieve the OptionSet values and Formatted values in the language the visitor have selected in the custom app.  This is always in the same language even when we change the culture for the Thread before we call Dynamics.

How can we pass the current language / culture to the OrganizationService so that it knows in what language it have to retrieve the fields?

Someone told me that this is based on the account used to connect to the CRM.  So if that's indeed the case then it means that if we have 5 languages that we need to have 5 connection strings and 5 OrgnaizationService instances that need to be called.  How should I handle this in a good way in that case?

Thanks for your answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I implemented was to use CallerId.
Before returning the client I fill the CallerId with a Guid.

The Guid is from a user configured with a specific language in Dynamics.
Based on the language I take a different user.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you can pass a culture to the `OrganizationService`, and I think having different connection strings would work if you want to go this route.

However, you can query the CRM to retrieve the localized labels for the option set you want, as described [here](https://community.adxstudio.com/products/adxstudio-portals/documentation/developers-guide/knowledge-base/getting-option-set-value-label/).
To sum it up, it's using a [RetrieveAttributeRequest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.xrm.sdk.messages.retrieveattributerequest?view=dynamics-general-ce-9), passing the entity logical name and field name and looping trough the result to get the labels.

```
var request = new RetrieveAttributeRequest
{
    EntityLogicalName = "incident",
    LogicalName = "casetypecode"
};
var response = organizationService.Execute(request) as RetrieveAttributeResponse;
var optionSetAttributeMetadata = response.AttributeMetadata as EnumAttributeMetadata;
foreach (var option in optionSetAttributeMetadata.OptionSet.Options)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Localized labels for option {option.Value}:");
    foreach (var locLabel in option.Label.LocalizedLabels)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Language {locLabel.LanguageCode}: {locLabel.Label}");
    }

    Console.WriteLine($"Localized description for option {option.Value}:");
    foreach (var locLabel in option.Description.LocalizedLabels)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Language {locLabel.LanguageCode}: {locLabel.Label}");
    }
}
```

The code in the link also add caching of already retrieved values, so that you only query the CRM once per option set.

Comment: Thanks colin,  this was also a direction I was thinking in first.  But it seems that there are also some Executes of OrganizationRequests that need to have the different language.   I have received also some info about Impersonation of the OrganizationService and or using the CallerId.  I need to investigate the possibilities of that.  Hopefully that could be a solution so that I don't have to completely rewrite my app.